# Partition MySQL: Error Code 1679 when trying to partion a table

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I get the error

> "Error Code 1697: Values for partition p0 must have type INT"

I also tried `FLOOR(0x080000)` which generated the same error and I also tried `INT(0x080000)` which generated a syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable`.`tbl_mac` (
`mac` MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`product` TINYINT(1) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`mac`)
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (mac) 
(
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0x080000),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (0x090000), 
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (0xFFFFFF)
);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why not just go with it and use int values that's how mac is stored anyway.

Comment: I hope you are not expecting a performance improvement by using partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

> In numeric contexts, MySQL treats a hexadecimal literal like a BIGINT
>   (64-bit integer). To ensure numeric treatment of a hexadecimal
>   literal, use it in numeric context. Ways to do this include adding 0
>   or using CAST(... AS UNSIGNED). For example, a hexadecimal literal
>   assigned to a user-defined variable is a binary string by default. To
>   assign the value as a number, use it in numeric context:

So, the solution is to use CAST

```
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (CAST(0x080000 AS UNSIGNED))
```

Comment: Did you try this ? I get ERROR 1564 (HY000): This partition function is not allowed.

Comment: I get the same error. **1564. This partition function is not allowed.** There [is a list of functions which are allowed during partitioning.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html) CAST is not one of them.

Comment: At least I know now where the problem is: **PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN(524288)** works.